# How to fix error when upload chunked video use facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, api, video, sdk

I have file index.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);

$data = [
  'title' => 'My Foo Video',
  'description' => 'This video is full of foo and bar action.',
];

$path = 'upload/video.mp4';

try {
  $response = $fb->uploadVideo('me', $path, $data, 'v2.3');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
var_dump($graphNode);
echo 'Video ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

After I go to address: mydomain.com/index.php, my video was uploaded on my facebook timeline.

But in index.php I give error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getGraphNode() on array in...

**Why? and how to fix this, i want get id video**

Comment: It would indicate that `$response` is an array and not an object with a callable method of `getGraphNode`

Comment: Yeah! thank you so much!